# Spring, JPA -- integration test of CRUD of entity which has many transitive dependencies of other entities

Tags: spring, testing, jpa, mocking, integration

I have entity e.g. `Product` which aggregates other entities such as `Category`. Those entities can also aggregate other entities and so on. Now I need to test my queries to database.

For simple CRUD I would create mock of `EntityManager`. But what if I have more complex query which I need to test for correct functionality. Then I probably need to persist entity (or more of them) and try to retrieve/update, whatever. I would also need to persist all entities on which my `Product` depends.

I don't like such approach. What is the best way to test such queries?

Thanks for replies.

---

Update -- example

Lets assume following entity structure
[image]

This structure is maintained by JPA implementation. For example `Product` class would look like this

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category; 

    @ManyToOne
    private Entity1 something;    
}
```

So now if I want to test any query used in DAO I need to create `Product` in database, but it is dependent on `Category` and `Entity1` and there is `@ManyToOne` annotation so values cannot be `null`. So I need to persist those entities too, but they have also dependencies.

I'm considering pre-creating entities such `Category`, `Entity1` and `Entity2` before test using SQL script or dbunit (mentioned by @chalimartines) which would save large amount of code, but I don't know whether it is good solution. I would like to know some best practices for such testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)` as

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/path/to/your/applicationContextTest.xml"})
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class YourClassTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //your crud
    }

}
```

**update**

You cant set the dependecies to null in order to avoid to persist them

Comment: You've maybe misunderstood me. I know how to test within Spring context. I just don't want to manually create entities on which `Product` entity is dependent and persist them. Because those entities may be also dependent on other entities and so I would end up persisting many entities just to test query that retrieves `Product`.

Comment: if you dont want to create and persist those entities, dont create them or use the existing ones. Give a concrete example

Comment: that is what i dont understand, why category and something can't be null?

Comment: You're right, it can be `null`. I had also `@NotNull` annotations on those `@ManyToOne`. I suppose nothing will happen when I remove them. If you update your answer according to your last comment i'll accept it so you can get some points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know other way, but for persisting Product and its dependencies you can use testing framework [DBunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) that helps you setup database data.